# not in as a function in filter-function

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a list of strings and i want to remove the strings having the strings in the list excludeList in them. Filter takes a function and a list, how can i "functionify" `excluded not in`? excludeList looks something like: `["A2123", "B323", "C22"]`

and the kolaDataList looks like: `["Very long string somethingsomething B323", "Lorem ipsum"]`

and the result should be `[Lorem ipsum]`

```
for excluded in excludeList:
    kolaDataList = filter((excluded not in), kolaDataList)
```

I suppose this would work in haskell but how do I do this in python?

Comment: I'm confused about what your output is supposed to be.  Do you want `kolaDataList` minus the elements that are common with `excludeList`?  Does order matter?

Comment: @mgilson, edited question now. I want to remove all strings which has ANY of the strings in excludeList in it

Comment: Thanks,  That's much more clear now.  I see what you're trying to do.

Comment: One issue people often overlook with `in` is accidental inclusion: if `kolaDataList == ["Almost but not quite B3234", "Lorem Ipsum"]`, then the first one will be removed if `"B323"` is in `excludeList`.  Is that what you want, or do you really want to operate on the level of words?

Comment: i guess i want to operate in words, but i don't think this will be any problem since all the combinations are unique as far as i know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [lambda](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda), or anonymous function:

```
for excluded in excludeList:
    kolaDataList = filter(lambda l: excluded not in l, kolaDataList)
```

Alternatively, just use a list comprehension:

```
for excluded in excludeList:
    kolaDataList = [l for l in kolaDataList if excluded not in l]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this as a list comprehension:

```
kolaDataList = [l for l in kolaDataList if excluded not in l]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's obvious to me now! List comprehensions ftw!

Comment: But I still "need" the for loop for the ``excluded``

Answer (score 1):

You must build your own function that filters your content, e.g. with `lambda` function. Let's build that generic function that filters values with your conditions:

```
generic_filter = lambda item, excludeList=[]: item not in excludeList
```

Now you can adapt this function to be used with `filter` using `functools.partial`.

```
import functools

# This function will be used with specific exclude list you pass it
my_filter = functools.partial(generic_filter, excludeList=excludeList)

# Apply filter
result = filter(my_filter, kolaDataList)
```

The advantage of creating middle generic function is that you can reuse it to apply do different exclusion lists.

Comment: Thx for an alternative way of doing it, but i think the answer with anonymous function is prettier and list comprehension even more so. :)